# How to filter row dataframe based on value of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to get filter based data rows from Genre column coming from another dataframe?

I have a movies dataframe as follows:

| Movie_Name | Genre | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Halloween | Crime, Horror, Thriller | 6.5 |
| Nope | Horror, Mystery, Sci-Fi | 6.9 |
| The Midnight Club | Drama, Horror, Mystery | 6.7 |
| The Northman | Action, Adventure, Drama | 7.1 |
| Prey | Action, Adventure, Drama | 7.2 |
| Uncharted | Action, Adventure | 6.3 |
| Sherwood | Crime, Drama, Mystery | 7.4 |

And I have a user dataframe as follows:

| User_Id | User_Name | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Christine | Horror, Thriller, Drama |

I want to get the following rows as output because the user likes horror, thriller, and drama genres.

| Movie_Name | Genre | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Halloween | Crime, Horror, Thriller | 6.5 |
| Nope | Horror, Mystery, Sci-Fi | 6.9 |
| The Midnight Club | Drama, Horror, Mystery | 6.7 |
| The Northman | Action, Adventure, Drama | 7.1 |
| Prey | Action, Adventure, Drama | 7.2 |
| Sherwood | Crime, Drama, Mystery | 7.4 |

How can I get the Movie rows where a value in the Genre column matches at least one of the User's Genre preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example use a for loop to get a list for each user on df2

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("db1.csv",header=[0]) # movies
df2=pd.read_csv("db2.csv",header=[0]) # users

for ir,row in df2.iterrows():
    gen=row["Genre"].replace(",","|").replace(" ","")
    filtereddf=df[df["Genre"].str.contains(gen)]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
pattern = user['Genre'].str.replace(', ', '|')[0]
result = movies.query('Genre.str.contains(@pattern)')
print(result)
```